# SEGFAULT - On C++ pure virtuals. Why?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, access-violation, virtual-functions, vtable

I am passing a pure-virtual base class pointer arround through C code as a `void *`.

When I dereference the base class in C++, the debugger is able to access all of its members. However, when I attempt to access a **pure virtual** function it SEGFAULTs/Access Violation. "Cannot access memory at 0xc" says the debugger (when I attempt to access a pure virtual function).

It is *possible* that the function is being called before the constructor returns, would this matter? What else should I look for? All the other variables seem to be intact.

**Code:**

```
the_socket_base* thisptr = reinterpret_cast<the_socket_base*>(watcher->data);  
thisptr->CallPureVirtualFunction();  
delete thisptr;
thisptr->CallSecondPureVirtualFunction();  //OOPS! It crashed
...  
watcher->data = this; // Associate socket with the watcher (Where 'this' is the base class)  
// NOTE THAT THE ABOVE ALWAYS HAPPENS IN THE CONSTRUCTOR
```

**UPDATE**: The code is *partially* working and I do suspect that the object gets deleted. Because it runs the read handler (which can delete itself) and then it runs the write handler without checking... So that's probably what it is.

---

### Answer

**FINAL UPDATE**: I wanted to clarify that Keith's comment was correct. I was deleting an object and trying to access it after it was deleted. Very simple mistake! `delete this;` is a tricky pitfall. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: It should be obvious from the stack trace in the debugger if the constructor has not returned.

Comment: We need to see the code. Especially were it is converted into void* and where it is converted from void*.

Comment: @Keith, The stack trace shows that the constructors have all returned. SEGFAULT derives from `main()` and libev's dispatch handlers.

Comment: @unixman83 - We need more code. Has the object simply already been deleted?

Comment: @Keith, I believe you are correct! The derived object was deleted, but the base destructor hadn't been run yet! That's what was so confusing. Thanks.

Comment: The code does not help. The point about code is so we can see the types (all of them). It is best to reduce it to the smallest piece of code that reproduces the problem and can still be compiled. Then post this code.

Comment: According to C++ standard, pure virtual function call is not a segfault, it's undefined behaviour. C++ standard even does not have a word "segfault".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete this; // Is dangerous, use with care
```

What I was doing is delete this; in the pure virtual function, returning immediately, and then calling another pure virtual function on the already deleted object.

- Pure virtual vtable will fail when object has already been deleted

Answer (score 2):

Without code, hard to say. Two possibilities OTOH:

- You're calling virtual functions directly or indirectly from constructor or destructor - you cannot do that.
- You're using multiple inheritance - and your casting via a void * breaks

Comment: I believe it may be bullet #1

Comment: @unixman83: You can implement a function (in the .cpp, not in the header) even though it's a pure virtual. If you do that, and put a breakpoint in this function, you may be able to find this easier.

Comment: You can call a virtual function, but you have to care which exactly is called (a call from constructor or destructor calls the method in the first base).

Comment: To clarify the first point: you cannot call *pure* virtual functions from a constructor or destructor. Calling normal virtual functions has well-defined behaviour.

Comment: @Erik - Good tip. If it breaks there then there really is a pure virtual call, if not, then more likely MI or some other reason for a broken object pointer.

Comment: @Erik, It still SEGFAULTS, however, the debugger correctly shows the function when I do what you suggest.

Comment: @VJo,Mike Seymor: To simply summarize the explanation of #1, `Virtual mechanism` is disabled inside constructors and destructor's.

Comment: @unixman83: You may need to show us enough code for reproduction. It does look like "thisptr" may be null though.

Comment: @Erik, I can confirm that thisptr is not NULL, and it points to a valid base class, but the derived class appears to be deleted already (which is likely what happened, see UPDATE)